# How can I report an answer generated by ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, flags, chatgpt

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Implementing Name Synchronization and Money Transfers in Transactions Model with Account Number Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76391344/implementing-name-synchronization-and-money-transfers-in-transactions-model-with)

There isn't any report icon on the answer I received from someone on Stack Overflow. The answer is not correct and I want to report it, but I can't.

[image: See]

Comment: You would use the flag feature; this is unlocked at 15 reputation.

Comment: It's not considered obvious enough CGPT to warrant deletion under the company's new AI policy anyway

Comment: You can flag *your own* post(s) at any reputation level. I'm not sure if that works for *answers* to your own question but, if you can't flag that (but you want to), then flag your own question (as "in need of moderator action) but explain **very clearly** that it's the answer that you think need their attention.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I would sy the "Copy code" before the code block makes it *very obvious*.

Comment: @ThomA Zoe *may* have been being uncharacteristically sarcastic.

Comment: I was not. I did not actually open the answer, so didn't see it said "copy code", which is definitely enough to qualify. Hopefully. They've been... Inconsistent in their internal guidance, to put it mildly

Comment: Well, that answer has been deleted by 'ordinary' Stack Overflow members. The Company haven't **yet** told us that we can't do that.

Comment: posting on meta and letting the meta effect deal with it seems effective (though it's gonna scale horribly)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I searched for "copy code" and I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279025/trying-to-connect-mongoose-to-my-mongodb-and-getting-in-browser-error .

Comment: The internal search ought to have a case-sensitive option (does it?). There are too many false positives in [these 2,155](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22Copy%20code%22&searchOn=3) (but the first 3 out of 6 aren't (2 in answers and 1 in the question)). Like for regular plagiarism, only the sloppiests posters get caught, which suggests the real number is much higher (sans the false positives).

Comment: Perhaps a better search would be [body:"Copy code" hascode:1 is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=body%3a%22Copy%20code%22%20hascode%3a1%20is%3aanswer&searchOn=3), @PeterMortensen .

Comment: @Thom A: Yes, that cuts it to 1/3.

Comment: Here's a SEDE query. 17 results. Some definite false positives. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1757915